# Reference Field Not Listed in Object Reference

Tags: object, reference

I was just going through the APEX developer guide and came accross this statement:

" *... For example, the Contact sObject has both an AccountId field of type ID, and an Account field of type Account that points to the associated sObject record itself.* "

However, when going through the Contact field reference I am not able to find the corresponding field for the Account reference - only for the Account Id (*AccountId*).

Thus my question: Why is it that the field for the Account reference is not listed in the field reference of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a lookup field, this is represented using an ID in the database. However, queries and query results allow a relationship name to be used to give the query languages an object-oriented quality (instead of the need to use typical SOQL JOIN-like syntax and result set processing). These relationships are not, in themselves, stored directly in the database; they are a means to providing a more object-based query mechanism.

Standard lookup fields are named *Something*Id and when you want to use the relationship it is simply called *Something*. On the other hand, if you add a custom lookup field, this is called *Something*__c and the equivalent relationship name is *Something*__r.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the document mentioned AccountId stores the Id of the Parent Account on the Contact Object which can be used to change the parent Account Id if needed.Also,Account field displays the Object record which redirects you to the parent Account record on the Contact Object.

Here the AccountId is an Standard field which can be accessed through apex but not available on the UI as field.

Comment: Yes that's what I understood but is there a particular reason why the field Account was not included in the field reference for the object Contact? [Contact Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contact.htm)

Comment: Because the actual relationship fields don't exist in the database but rather provide a means to express queries and query results in a more object-oriented manner, avoiding the need to use obviously JOIN-like structures. There are well-defined ways to turn lookup field names into relationship names (i.e. remove "Id" from the end of standard fields, change "__c" to "__r" for custom fields).